# Import csv files into mysql - LOAD DATA statement duplication

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

The csv file is created right BEFORE i execute the following statement which is to import csv file into mysql using c#

```
MySqlCommand insertgazeCoords = new MySqlCommand();
insertgazeCoords.Connection = c;
insertgazeCoords.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/L31303/Desktop/WriteTextFile/" + gazeID + ".csv' INTO TABLE eyetracker.gazecoords FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' SET gazeAreaID = NULL;";
insertgazeCoords.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Gaze Coordinates has been inserted.");
```

The data in the csv file looks something like this

```
XValue|YValue|CoordA|CoordB
10    |20    |30    |40
20    |10    |40    |20
30    |30    |20    |30
```

However, when i try inserting into mySQL it'll look like this

```
XValue|YValue|CoordA|CoordB
10    |20    |30    |40
10    |20    |30    |40
20    |10    |40    |20
10    |20    |30    |40
20    |10    |40    |20
30    |30    |20    |30
```

See the pattern?

```
XValue|YValue|CoordA|CoordB
10    |20    |30    |40

10    |20    |30    |40
20    |10    |40    |20

10    |20    |30    |40
20    |10    |40    |20
30    |30    |20    |30
```

I don't want the repeated data, i want the data in mysql to appear just like the ones in csv files.

I used the following code below to insert into mysql, did i do anything wrong?

The code used to create csv files

```
  if (!File.Exists(filePath))
  {
  File.Create(filePath).Close();
  }
  string delimiter = ",";
  string[][] output = new string[][]{
  new string[]{null , gazeID.ToString(), XValue.ToString(), YValue.ToString(), currentTime.ToString(), pupilDiaX.ToString(), pupilDiaY.ToString()}};
  int length = output.GetLength(0);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int index = 0; index < length; index++){
  sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index])); 
  }
  File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());


 MySqlCommand insertgazeCoords = new MySqlCommand();
 insertgazeCoords.Connection = c;
 insertgazeCoords.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/L31303/Desktop/WriteTextFile/" + gazeID + ".csv' INTO TABLE eyetracker.gazecoords FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' SET gazeAreaID = NULL;";
 insertgazeCoords.ExecuteNonQuery();
 Console.WriteLine("Gaze Coordinates has been inserted.");
```

Comment: are you sure you're only running this once? and with one file? it seems like you're iterating while building the CSV and importing after every row inserted

Comment: I have only one file. Do you have any idea what kind of statement that might be causing the iteration? i have a for loop running a few lines before the load data statement

Comment: Can you post the full code? creation of CSV + insertion

Comment: Done. I added the code i used to create csv. I did not do any insert statement because i'm trying to speed up the process of inserting data into mysql (hence the csv).

Comment: Could you display the generated file and see that it has the correct data? It seems that you might not be initializing your string "sb" at the top of each iteration in the loop and hence it accumulating the records from previous iterations.